# cakephp 3 img pending request, image doesn't load

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, cakephp-3.1

I'm developing with cakephp 3 right now. I have a controller that has a img in it's view. The problem is that it is pending and doesn't load (in chrome not in firefox).

One factor could be the authentication I set up just recently. However I turned it off in the AppController and it still doesn't load.

Any ideas where this problem comes form?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now:
It was indeed the authentication. When it get's turned off it doesn't work immediatly. One has to close the tab and load the page in another tab.

So turning the authentication off and opening the page in a new tab fixed it.

Note: If you load the Auth-component in AppController then you can deactivate it in a sub-controller by just implementing the initialize-method and not calling parent::initialize ...